# Unable to install Webgoat on AWS. I get error about Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install webgoat on AWS. I am following the instructions given on https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat
I can get it up and running on my local box. But when I try to deploy it on AWS it gives error and complains about Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json.

I go to elastic beanstalk. Then I create an application (of docker type). It asks me for the code and I give it the zip file from github. After several minutes it gives errors about Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json.

Webgoat has several Dockerfiles, but no Dockerrun.aws.json. I am not sure how to resolve this. 
What is the best way to deploy webgoat in aws?
Will appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to install it using the info provided on these two sources.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html
- and https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat

Here are the steps:

- sudo yum update -y
- sudo yum install -y docker
- sudo service docker start
- sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user     (Restart the server)
- sudo docker pull webgoat/webgoat-8.0
- sudo docker run -p 80:8080 -it webgoat/webgoat-8.0 /home/webgoat/start.sh

Make sure to modify the security group associated with the aws instance to allow http traffic. After that you should be able to access the app with this url:
http://:80/WebGoat/login